# Reference private property in class from second class using phpdoc?

Tags: php, class, phpdoc

```
namespace {
  class ClassOne {

    private $table = 'myTable';

  }
}


namespace private {
  class ClassTwo {

    public function __construct(\stdClass $data){}

  }
}
```

And basically what I want to do is document a reference to the `$table` property from `ClassOne` in the `__construct` function

I was hoping I could do something like

```
/**
 * @param \stdClass $data Row from the @see \competitionsModel::$table Table
 */
```

Comment: This would imply that the second class relies on a private element of another class, and that is as per the definition of the "private" modifier just so very wrong.

Comment: Not quite, actually there is a public method inside `ClassOne` that returns a row from the database table `$table`, I am trying to document what table the data comes from basically.

Comment: So what's wrong with referring to that public method instead?

Comment: Because there are several public methods that return the data, some will only return one row, and call the second class with it, others will return a subset, and call the class on every row, and others will return all rows, and call the class on every row, the only thing in common is that it all comes from that table..

Comment: Think of it it reference to calling `$item = new ClassOne();` `$item->get($id);` or `$item->getAll()` they both use `ClassTwo`